# Js- button With options to write in A TextArea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example When you click On a button it shows you options to choose from And whatever you choose Gets written inside the textArea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery you canmake use of $.append('id or class','html or data to append') or $.html('id or class','html or content to put in place')

If you are using purely javascript this may be a good spot to make use of `innerHTML()`

If will allow you to achieve the same functionality(in a different manner as this works as a method of a given element).

Answer (score 0):

The button with the option to choose option called `select` tag. You need a script that will "take" the selected value from the `select` tag and will put it in the `textarea`. So you can see the code (with `jQuery`) that do this.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $('textarea').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Choose option</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>  
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
<hr />
<textarea></textarea>
```